# How can i extract data that contains specific string from a file into an array and getting everything in a single array

Tags: arrays, matlab

am trying to get some specific data from a text file, although am getting the data, but they are coming as in individually i.e. each result is not saving together.

I am trying to extract a set of specific line in a large text file, i want to extract all the lines in which the word occurs, and after getting the lines, i want them together in an array or a table, i got it but the files are extracting into individual columns.

```
queryline = 'mybeat';
fID = fopen('log1.txt');
result = [];
while ~feof(fID);
    tline = fgetl(fID);
    if ~isempty(strfind(tline, queryline))
        formatspec = sprintf(tline, '%[yyyy-mm-ddTI4:hh:mm]D%C%C%f%f%f%f','\n',queryline, )
          result =[sscanf(tline,formatspec)];
      end
  end
fclose(fID);
```

but my result i coming one after the other, i need all the result in one array of cells. This is an example of results am getting,

```
formatspec =
```

2017-10-02T23:48:51.93Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:48:57.58Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:03.24Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:08.90Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:14.56Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:20.22Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:25.87Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:31.53Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:37.19Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:42.84Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:48.50Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

2017-10-02T23:49:54.15Z 'I|Beat:6548|mybeat:A1201:A'

formatspec =

I even tried using string join, so i tried to imporve the code  by adding this

```
  one_str = strjoin( formatspec, '\n' );

    result  = textscan( one_str, '%[yyyy-mm-ddTI4:hh:mm]D%C%C%f%f%f%f', 'CollectOutput',true ); 
    %   make sure that only results are included in the output
    assert( strcmp( unique(result{1}), queryline )     ...
        ,   'Non-result rows included in result' )
    out = result{2};
end
```

after the loop, but am still having a

```
Error using strjoin (line 52)
```

First input must be a 1xN cell array of strings.

Error in Untitled5 (line 19)
            one_str = strjoin( formatspec, '\n' );

please can someone help. i can attach the file if you want

This is a sample of the log file

```
2017-10-02T14:36:14.01Z 'D|Beat:6528|evtT:361178'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6553|mybeat:81301:P'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6555|MyNodesDump:1'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6555|1301'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6556|MyRtrsDump:0'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'D|Beat:4490|nxtIdx:0'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'D|Beat:6604|BFlg:0 SFC:0'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6666|ldr:0'
2017-10-02T14:36:14.08Z 'D|Beat:2106|B->'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6553|mybeat:81301:P'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6555|MyNodesDump:3'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6555|1201'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6555|1301'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6555|1302'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6556|MyRtrsDump:5'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6556|b:21103 r:1302 p:1401'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6556|b:61202 r:1301 p:1203'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6556|b:91402 r:1301 p:1402'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6556|b:B1102 r:1201 p:1101'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6556|b:D1602 r:1302 p:1502'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'D|Beat:4506|nxtIdx:0'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6666|ldr:21103'
2017-10-02T14:42:18.76Z 'D|Beat:1197|Rcv<-B, s:1201'
```

am trying to extract for example every line that contains mybeat in into an array and getting the date, time and second plus the numbers beside mybeat into another table.. like

```
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z   81301
```

into another separate array.

The problem i was having is that when i ran the script i wrote, the output is coming out individually and its getting the files into a single array, so i can't even access them all except i copy them from the command prompt.

Comment: I think you typo-ed or had a copy paste error in your example.  You formatSpec line has some invalid syntax and doesn't make much sense the way it is written ... wouldn't give the output you show.  I think your question would be a lot more understandable if you just showed us a sample of your log file and tell us what you want to extract from it.

Comment: I just edited the question and i added a sample of the log file there,  kindly check

Comment: About how large is the Log file in MB?  Is it possible to read the entire file at once instead of line by line?

Comment: the log file is around 30mb, pretty large, but i think it should be able to read it line by line...

Comment: I am reading through it and testing your textscan line on 1 line from your sample log file ... and it is failing miserably.  It is not formed correctly to work at all.  This will crash as written on the first loop.  So either the code posted above is not your "real" code or you never made it very far.  I will see if I can rework it return your desired output. ... stand by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I couldn't get textscan with that format spec to run on your example.  It seems badly formed so I don't know how you ever got any output.  However, here is an option to try.  This abandons the textscan and uses a regexp.  Also note I added a line to your example so that there was  letter in the otherNum section per your comment below.

queryline = 'mybeat';
    fID = fopen('log1.txt');
    k = 1;
    while ~feof(fID)
        tline = fgetl(fID);
        if ~isempty(strfind(tline, queryline))
            temp= regexp(tline,['(?^[0-9,-:T]*)Z.*' queryline ':(?[0-9A-Z]*):'] ,'tokens');
            outTime(k) = datetime(temp{1}{1},'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS');
    %         outNum(k) = str2double(temp{1}{2});
            outNum{k} = temp{1}{2};
            matchedLines{k} = tline;  %Store the raw line
            k = k+1;
        end
    end
    fclose(fID);

This gives results that look like this:

```
outTime = 
  1×3 datetime array
   02-Oct-2017 14:36:14   02-Oct-2017 14:42:18   02-Oct-2017 14:48:14

outNum =
       '81301'    '81301'    'C81301'

>> char(matchedLines)
ans =
2017-10-02T14:36:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6553|mybeat:81301:P' 
2017-10-02T14:42:18.70Z 'I|Beat:6553|mybeat:81301:P' 
2017-10-02T14:48:14.03Z 'I|Beat:6553|mybeat:C81301:P'
```

This will append to outTime & outNum in the loop which will get slow if there are a lot of these.  So you have a couple of options.  Try to read the file all at once or loop through once to get a count of how many times your queryline appears.  Then initialize your outXXXX variables to the correct size ahead of time.

Here is an example of doing it without a while loop assuming you can read the entire file at once without having memory issues (30MB isn't that big).

```
queryline = 'mybeat';
fID = fopen('log1.txt');
C = textscan(fID,'%s','delimiter','\n');
fclose(fID);
C = C{1};
[temp matchedLines] = regexp(C,['(?<date>^[0-9,-:T]*)Z.*' queryline ':(?<otherNum>[0-9A-Z]*):.*'] ,'tokens','match');
matchedLines = [matchedLines{:}]';
temp = [temp{:}];
temp = reshape([temp{:}],2,[])';
outTime  = datetime(temp(:,1),'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS');
otherNum = temp(:,2);
```

Comment: Thank you, i will try this out now, i didn't used textscan inntially, i was using the result function to call out the output, but was getting no result,  something like this "result = [result; sscanf(tline,formatspec)];"    the result was an empty array, and that's why i tried textscan, maybe it will be able to read through the formatspec results, but thanks,i will check it out now and get back to you asap. regards

Comment: Ok.  Let me know of if you run into issues.  Also please accept the answer if it fixes your problem.

Comment: Hello, thank you, sorry for my late response, went to work since. i have some small issues and questions, 1. am having a small error when i ran the first code, its says"                                       Reference to non-existent element of a cell array.

Error in mx (line 8)
        outTime(k) = datetime(temp{1}{1},'InputFormat','yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SS');"       also if i want this line "':(?<otherNum>[0-9]*):']" to detect Alphabet as well, cuz some of the output has character in them, like A1201 or C13C20  not only numbers.

Comment: sorry if i may ask, is there anywhere i can improve my initial code, such that i can get all the entire lines, joined together,

Comment: I edited my answer based on your comments.  otherNum now returns a cell array instead of a double since it can have chars in it.  Also I added `matchedLines` a cell array that contains the raw line if it matches the criteria.

Comment: Hello Friend, i need to ask you a question.if you can help please kindly do, regarding the previous question you answered for me , i was trying to extract some other queryline, but am getting a weird result. Please kindly reply so i can post the question. thanks

Comment: @idrisbadmus  No problem I found your new question and posted an answer there.